# Unexcpected loading after win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y)) in Python 2.7.11

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, winapi, pywin32

Recently got a new computer, installed python, and went to go run a piece of code. After the code did not work, a little debugging, and a hard slap to computer I am out of ideas.

After setting the cursor position the mouse has a small loading symbol next to it.  The code is supposed to click after setting the cursor position, but it is not clicking. (I think it is due to whatever 'loading' is occurring)

Below is my code.

Also; I've installed a few versions of python (3.5.2, 2.7.11, 2.7.12) and their corresponding version of pywin32, but none have worked.

Any ideas?

```
import win32api, win32con
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
click(150,95)
```

Comment: By a quick search of the win32 API reference site, it seems that the function "mouse_event" is not longer used.

Comment: And since i don't know much about Python nor Win32 API. I will provide you with some links.

MouseInput : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273(v=vs.85).aspx

SendInput : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I see. How do I find the new (if any) syntax?  I'm poking around the windows api index that microsoft has on their website, but can not seem to find it.

Comment: Either you seek other alternatives, maybe something like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoGUI . 
OR
https://github.com/PyUserInput/PyUserInput
.
Otherwise i guess you have to make your Python code 'simulate' same datastructures and pass them to the function call. But a decent amount of Python knowledge is required for that i guess..

Comment: Just used PyAutoGui. Successful install but the same problem persists.  It now appears that the script is failing to even click into the window. They are not registering at all. Also, pyautogui could just be a directory using mouse-event(s), or no?

Comment: According to the source ode to the PyAutoGUI, they are having problems with using the new call SendInput(), so they went back to use the old method. But the old method won't work on new windows systems.

Comment: @MrSykkox none of that is true

Comment: @MrSykkox: Nothing in the documentation for [mouse_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260.aspx) even remotely hints to your made up claims. `mouse_event` still works on all versions of Windows. [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) is a better choice, but it's not the only API available. Everything you said here is complete and utter bogus.

Comment: Welp. I ate the bogus. Became the bogus. What a waste of time!

Comment: Why aren't you using automation anyway.